# What is the purpose of fc-cache in fontconfig?

Tags: fonts, freetype, text-rendering, fontconfig, harfbuzz

i went through the documentation of fontconfig and i could understand the purpose of fc-match and fc-list. I am not understanding what does fc-cache does? How does it help device to understand things related to fonts?

Could anyone explain what is the purpose of fc-cache in fontconfig?

thanks.

Answer (score 10):

> [fc-cache](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fc-cache) scans the font directories on the system and builds font
>   information cache files for applications using fontconfig for their
>   font handling.

And  caching is used to improve  performance by shortening data access times, reduce latency and improve input/output.